# How to structure Entityframework DB Contexts

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I haven't been able to find any answers online for this.

1. What are the advantages/disadvantages of using Multiple DB Contexts against using a single?
2. Is the below solution ok for setting related objects, (when saving to DB) (to make it more efficient, because I already have the ID, no need to fetch object)
3. I've heard its reccommened to use contexts like `Using(MyContext c = MyContext) {}`, at the moment I'm using the default MVC way, of having the context instantiated in the controller, is this ok?

   ```
     Person P = new Person(); 
     P.QuickSetCar(CarID); 
     db.People.Add(P); 
     db.saveChanges();
   ```

   and

   ```
   private void QuickSetCar(int CarID)
   {
     if(this.Car == null) {
       Car C = new Car();
       C.ID = ID;
       this.Car = C;
    }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Using multiple contexts is always a disadvantage unless you have no choice (e.g. your data is dispersed across multiple databases).
2. Almost, but you can simplify your new car initialization to:

   ```
   private void QuickSetCar(int CarID) {
     if(this.Car == null)
       this.Car = new Car(){ ID = CarID };
   }
   ```
3. That's fine.  Just don't use more than one context for the duration of the web transaction (request/response) and don't keep it around for longer than that either.

Answer (score 1):

1. Multiple contexts are normally only useful for very large models spread over multiple databases. If you are starting a project it is normally best to use a single context.
2. Your method for using IDs is fine.
3. Creating contexts within controllers is certainly workable but I would strongly suggest against it. This approach is often shown in demos and for basic scaffolding but in real world applications it is not a great idea. Large amounts of code will often be duplicated by instatiating and querying contexts in each controller. Also have a central repository will allow for much easier caching to improve performance.

Comment: Thanks!! Re: #3, my code is DRY, what do you mean by a central repository?

Comment: The repo is just a central location for all interactions with the context. It is hard for code to be DRY as the project grows if you are opening and querying contexts in each controller. A good starter for the repository pattern is at http://blog.appharbor.com/2012/10/31/repository-pattern-and-convention-based-entity-framework-code-first